# SqlQuery one named placeholders several times

Tags: c++, sql, qt, binding

I tried

```
  QSqlQuery query;
  query.prepare("DELETE FROM names WHERE id_col = :ID OR id_parent = :ID");
  query.bindValue(":ID", idVal);
  query.exec();
```

assuming that idVal will be binded two times, but executing this query only rows with id_parent = idVal is deleted, with id_col = idVal remains undeleted. So only second time idVal was binded to the query.

When I rewrite it to

```
  QSqlQuery query;
  query.prepare("DELETE FROM names WHERE id_col = ? OR id_parent = ?");
  query.bindValue(0, idVal);
  query.bindValue(1, idVal);
  query.exec();
```

everything worked as expected.

Is it a way to use one named placeholders several time in QSqlQuery?

Comment: **Side note:** This is not answering you question, but you can `JOIN` with delete and use only one placeholder. Something like: `DELETE n FROM names n INNER JOIN names p ON p.id_col = n.id_parent WHERE id_col = :ID`.

Comment: For posterity, I found a hack for a related problem when you're doing _select_ statements.  Use the [`with clause`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) like this: `with my_id as (values(:id)) select * from names where id = (select * from my_id) or parent_id = (select * from my_id)`

Comment: *sheepishly* : This constraint is removed in qt 5, so workarounds are only needed prior to qt 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [QSqlQuery::bindValue() documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#bindValue):

> **Values cannot be bound to multiple locations in the query**, eg:
>
> INSERT INTO testtable (id, name, samename) VALUES (:id, :name, :name)
>
> Binding to name will bind to the first :name, but not the second.

The last sentence appears to be slightly wrong as it looks like it binds to the second :name, but either way, this clearly states what you are trying to achieve is not supported by Qt.

Your options are to stick with the workaround you already have, or use the solution provided by Mahmoud Gamal in the comment to your question.

Comment: In the documentation of Qt 5.9.1 (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#bindValue) this text is removed and the multiple binding indeed works.

Answer (score 1):

To see what query was actually executed, you can use `QSqlQuery::executedQuery()`.

And you should explicitly set values for placeholders:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("DELETE FROM names WHERE id_col = :ID_COL OR id_parent = :ID_PAR");
query.bindValue(":ID_COL", idVal);
query.bindValue(":ID_PAR", idVal);
query.exec();
```

Also it will be useful if you will need refactoring in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first do:

```
select * from names where :ID in 
((select id_col FROM names WHERE id_col = :ID)
OR
(select id_parent FROM names WHERE id_parent = :ID)
);
```

if the above select returned the right data then use the following as your query:

```
delete from names where :ID in 
((select id_col FROM names WHERE id_col = :ID)
OR
(select id_parent FROM names WHERE id_parent = :ID)
);
```